# Positioning text according to the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check this out http://jsfiddle.net/e8UQn/

In the display screen, you can see the the text at the bottom position when you drag the scroll bar down, I've set the position of **#text-box** to **absolute** which is necessary to show the position at the specified **top and left** position.

What I need is when the browser shrinks, the backstretch image is looking perfect, but the **text** needs to modify its position so that the scroll bar should not be shown.

There should not be any change in top and left property, because those values are dynamically derived from my web application which is necessary. Is there any possibility in changing the values dynamically according to the screen size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

updated:

try this:

```
var t = $(window).height() - $("#text-box").outerHeight();
$("#text-box").css("top", t);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8UQn/3/

Comment: No @Raminson there should not be any change in top and left property which are derived from my web application. Btw thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to position `#text-box` relative to the bottom of the window:

```
#text-box {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    bottom: 20px; /* This value here */
    left: 51px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8UQn/2/

If you don't have the ability to change that output, overwrite the `top` value:

```
#text-box {
    top: 'auto';
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: @rnk You cannot keep the same `top` value. Sorry.